# Make Client With Spring OAUTH2

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I've an Oauth2 Server implemented with spring-security-oauth2, works well, authenticate the user, refresh token, and if i pass an authentication header "Bearer xxxx" to a rest endpoint in it, works well too.

The problem, I want to create a rest service that comunicate with the oauth server passing the header "Bearer xxxx" and aproves the connection, there are any kind of solution for that? i'm really desesperated...

The Service-Auth =>

**AuthorizationServer:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
}
```

**ResourceServer:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

**Security Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    public static Properties getProps() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("crowd.properties")) {
            prop.load(in);
        }
        return prop;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/secure/hello");
    }

    @Bean
    public CrowdUserDetailsService crowdUserDetailsService() throws IOException {
        CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl cusd = new CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl();
        cusd.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        return cusd;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return new AuthenticationBasic();
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/oauth2
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.schema=oauth2
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Test connection every hour Database
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000

# Web server
server.port=8080
server.contextPath=/api/v1/secure
```

The Service-Client =>

**Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**RestController:**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello User!";
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/secure/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/secure/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: header
    resource:
      tokenInfoUri: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/secure/oauth/check_token
server:
  port: 8082
  contextPath: /api/v1/auth
```

Comment: Did you check these samples  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2

Comment: I've cheked the samples but I still without know how to implement a rest api that catch the Authorization header, send it to the authorization server and decide if the user can use the api rest

Comment: You could ask try in https://gitter.im where you could post questions on git projects like "spring-projects/spring-security-oauth" ...good luck..

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this question?